# sitecore strange behavior for only space in url

Tags: sxa, multisite

I have a strange issue, and it seems like related to configuration but I don't know how to fix it. 
when user add space to url like http://my.local/%20/ I see an error
like

```
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The configSource file 'App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config' is also used in a parent, this is not allowed.
```

I just wonder how to solve it on multisite solution?

Comment: for multisite you must have the same related path to 404 page for all sites